# How do you do qualified superclass constructor invocation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, constructor, inner-classes

I'm using Kotlin and Java together. I am looking for a way to extend a non-static nested class from Kotlin, but I have no idea how to do it.

From the [JLS 1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html):

Example **8.8.7.1-1**. *Qualified Superclass Constructor Invocation*

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {}
}
class ChildOfInner extends Outer.Inner {
    ChildOfInner() { (new Outer()).super(); }
}
```

I've tried to do like below but it doesn't really work in Kotlin:

```
class ChildOfInner(): Outer().Outer.Inner()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Kotlin we can inherit `inner` classes in this way:

```
class ChildClass : Outer() {
    inner class ChildOfInner : Outer.Inner() {

    }
}
```

So firstly we must inherit `Outer` class and then we are able to inherit `Inner` class.

Comment: I am trying to make a new Inner instance outside the Outer class. Is there any way to extend the Inner class without an Outer class inheritance? Btw, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I don't see how we can do that for now, seems it's  the only way.